# Is it possible to convert GroupCollection to List or IEnumerable?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to convert a `GroupCollection` to a `List` or an `IEnumerable`?
I'm referring to the `GroupCollection` in regular expressions.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Sure

```
GroupCollection col = ...;
IEnumerable<Group> enumerable = col.Cast<Group>();
List<Group> list = col.Cast<Group>().ToList();
```

Comment: Awesome. I used this to do this: `var videoId = matches[0].Groups.Cast<Group>().ToList().Last(o => o.Value != "");`

Answer (score 9):

Here's one-liner version:

```
new Regex("[your regex goes here]").Matches(stringThatYouAreTryingToExtractGroupsFrom)[0].Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Where(o => o.Value != "").Select(o => o.Value)
```

This will `throw` an exception if there are no matches. I am also skipping the original `[0]` group that captures full regex and filtering out empty groups.

Comment: are you sure this answer fits the question?

Comment: @Byyo Hi, I am pretty certain, why do you ask?

Comment: this RegEx makes no sense -1

Comment: @Byyo this regex is for illustration purposes only, any sensible person will understand to replace it with his own, I will however put explanation just for you :) .