# GroupCollection.First builds in netcoreapp but not in netstandard

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am getting errors building `netcoreapp` code in `netstandard` I cannot resolve.

The following code compiles in `netcoreapp2.2`:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace TestNamespace
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public static Group Example(string str, string pattern) =>
            Regex.Match(str, pattern).Groups.First();
    }
}
```

But if I change it to `netstandard2.0` then `.First` fails to compile with:

```
  Class1.cs(10, 46): [CS1061] 'GroupCollection' does not contain a definition for 'First' and no accessible extension method 'First' accepting a first argument of type 'GroupCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

However if I use "go to code" in Jetbrains Rider, the disassembly for `GroupCollection` resolves to `System.Text.RegularExpressions, Version=4.2.1.0` which implements `IList`. I have manually added this assembly and `System.Linq` but the error persists.

Any idea what is happening? Any idea of a fix?

Comment: You could use `Groups[0]` instead of `Groups.First()`.

Comment: yup, it's a simplified example, in reality there were additional uses of linq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GroupCollection` in later versions of .NET Core [implements](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.RegularExpressions/src/System/Text/RegularExpressions/GroupCollection.cs) `IList<Group>`. `IList<Group>` is sufficient for LINQ extension methods (like `First`) to work.

`GroupCollection` in .NET Framework (or earlier versions of .NET Core) does [not](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/RegexGroupCollection.cs,5f5cf4d9e6dada2b) implement that interface (it implements the older (non-generic) interfaces only). Thus, you can't use `First` without [casting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2464674/34092) it.

If you do decide to [`Cast`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2464674/34092), then the same code will work for everything (.NET Core / Standard / Framework).