# Why is it not possible to call .ToArray directly on GroupCollection even though it's IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464668/is-it-possible-to-convert-groupcollection-to-list-or-ienumerable) I need to specify that a `GroupCollection` is `IEnumerable` in order to use extension methods that work on `IEnumerable` on it:

```
GroupCollection groups =  Regex.Match(content, @"key : (.+?)-").Groups;

IEnumerable<Group> groupsEnumerable = groups;

var foo = groupsEnumerable.Select(x=>x.Value).ToArray(); //this works fine
var bar = groups.Select(x=>x.Value).ToArray(); //while this does not compile
```

Why do I have to tell the `GroupCollection` instance that it is an `IEnumerable` in order to call the extension methods on it that are based on `IEnumerable`?

Added a screenshot of the error (.NET 6)

[image: error]

Comment: Not true - both `Regex.Match("aa", @"key : (.+?)-").Groups.ToArray<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group>()` and `Regex.Match("aa", @"key : (.+?)-").Groups.ToArray<KeyValuePair<string,System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group>>()` compile just fine...

Comment: It would be good to know what errors the compiler emits. They are usually helpful in understanding why it refuses to compile something. It's likely because of `GroupCollection` implementing both `IEnumerable<Group>` and `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group>>` but the compiler error would really clear that up.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov added a screenshot of the error. At least for me it's strange...

Comment: @moreON same, please check the screenshot. So you are saying this should be reported to Microsoft?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that [`GroupCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.groupcollection?view=net-7.0) implements two different versions of the `IEnumerable<>` interface:

```
public class GroupCollection : 
System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group>,
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group>>,
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group>, 
System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group>, 
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group>>, 
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyCollection<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group>, 
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary<string,System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group>, 
System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Group>, 
System.Collections.IList
```

The compiler doesn't know which generic type to pass into the `Enumerable.Select<>()` method: Should it use a `Group` or a `KeyValuePair<string, Group>`?

You can see the same behavior from the following code:

```
new Foo().Select(i => i);

public class Foo : IEnumerable<int>, IEnumerable<string>
{
    IEnumerator<int> IEnumerable<int>.GetEnumerator() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    IEnumerator<string> IEnumerable<string>.GetEnumerator() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

By casting it explicitly, you remove this ambiguity. A slightly less verbose (but slightly less well-performing) alternative is to call `.Cast<Group>()`

```
var bar = groups.Cast<Group>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Or you can specify generic parameters to the method explicitly:

```
var bar = groups.Select<Group, string>(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Or specify the parameter type in the delegate you pass in:

```
var bar = groups.Select((Group x) => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: RATS. You beat me to it! This is, to my knowledge, the correct answer.

Comment: Should it just pick one, or it wouldn't be a safe behavior?

Comment: @meJustAndrew when there is ambiguity, it's up to the developer to remove it by explicitly stating which one to use.

Comment: Another way to disambiguate the Linq methods is by specifying a type for expression parameters. e.g. `new Foo().Select( (string i) => "" );`

Comment: Good call-out, @moreON! I've incorporated that into my answer.

Answer (score 2):

[`GroupCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.groupcollection?view=net-7.0) implements two `IEnumerable<T>` interfaces - `IEnumerable<Group>` and `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Group>>`, so compiler can't determine which one to use for the `Select` (and other [`Enumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable?view=net-7.0#methods) extension methods).

Another approach is to specify the type in the labmda:

```cs
var bar = groups.Select((Group x) => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Or specify generic parameters explicitly:

```cs
var bar = groups.Select<Group, string>(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Or using `OfType`/`Cast`:

```cs
var bar = groups.OfType<Group>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Though the latter one in theory can break in feature if [internal enumerator implementation](https://source.dot.net/#System.Text.RegularExpressions/System/Text/RegularExpressions/GroupCollection.cs,234) will be changed.

Comment: The [`OfType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype) has filtering behavior, which makes me feel uncomfortable with using it for casting purposes.